# How draw on gtk window without generating expose event

Tags: python, pygtk

I am doing a project in PyGtk for monitoring a performance of system.
I have developed almost of the code for purpose.But now i have a problem in it.
My problem is that i am repainting all my stuff on expose-event and i want to draw on window without generating expose event.Reason for that is, i am plotting a graph on expose-event,but when i resize window it is not showing the perfect reading, i want to plot graph when window is idle and window is not resizing and when window gets resize it should not plot a graph.I tried for configure event but doesn't success to me.
please help me.
Please reply me soon.
thank you

here is my complete code:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require(`2.0`)
import gtk
import cairo
import gobject
import random, sys, thread, time
from gtk import gdk

class Monitor(gtk.DrawingArea):

        ##__gsignals__ = {
                        ##"configure-event" : "override"
                        ##}

        count = 0
        coord = []
        mem_coord = []
        x1, y1 = 0, 0
        str1 = []
        max_mem = 0
        mem_usage = 0
        name = ""
        G = 2
        def __init__(self,parent,name):


                super(Monitor,self).__init__()
                self.coord.append(0)
                self.connect("expose-event",self.do_on_expose)
                self.name = name                        
                gobject.timeout_add(1000,self.draw_loop)

        def get_mem_data(self):
                f = open("/proc/meminfo","r")
                str2 = f.readline().split(" ")[:]
                self.max_mem = int(str2[len(str2)-2])
                for i in range(5):
                        str2 = f.readline().split(" ")[:]
                str3 = int(str2[len(str2)-2])
                f.close()
                return str3

        def get_mem_usage(self):
                self.mem_usage = self.get_data()
                val = (self.mem_usage * 100) / self.max_mem
                return val

        def get_cpu_data(self):

                f = open("/proc/stat","r")
                str2 = f.readline().split(" ")[2:6]
                f.close()
                for i in range(len(str2)):
                        str2[i] = int(str2[i])                
                return str2

        def get_cpu_usage(self):
                str2 = self.get_data()
                for i in range(len(self.str1)):
                        self.str1[i] = str2[i] - self.str1[i]        
                val = 100 - (self.str1[len(self.str1) - 1] * 100.00 / sum(self.str1))
                for i in range(len(self.str1)):
                        self.str1[i] = str2[i]        
                return val

        def draw_loop(self):
                self.queue_draw()
                return True

        def do_configure_event(self, event):

                self.cr=self.window.cairo_create()
                self.draw_grid(self.G)
                self.draw_graph()
                gtk.Window.do_configure_event(self, event)

        def do_on_expose(self,widget,event):
                self.cr=widget.window.cairo_create()
                self.draw_grid(self.G)
                self.draw_graph()

        def draw_graph(self):

                val = random.randint(1,100)##self.get_usage(self.resource)    ##random.randint(1,100)     
                print "val = ",val           
                if self.count<256 :
                        self.count=self.count+1
                        self.coord.append(val)
                else:
                        self.coord.pop(0)
                        self.coord.append(val)

                val = (self.y1+self.y2-3) - ((val*(self.y2-6))/100)


                x=self.x1 + self.x2 - 3
                self.cr.move_to(x,val)
                self.cr.set_source_rgb(255,0,0)

                for i in range(self.count,-1,-1):
                        if x > self.x1+3:
                                val = (self.y1+self.y2-3) - ((self.coord[i]*(self.y2-6))/100)
                                self.cr.line_to(x,val)
                                self.cr.move_to(x,val)
                                x=x-5
                        else:
                                break

                self.cr.stroke()
                return False

        def draw_grid(self,G):
                size=self.window.get_size()
                height = (size[1] / G) - 30
                self.x1, self.y1 = 20, 20
                self.x2, self.y2 = size[0]-(2*self.x1), height
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2
                for i in range(G):
                    self.cr.set_source_rgb(0,0,0)
                    self.cr.rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2)
                    self.cr.fill()
                    self.cr.stroke()
                    self.cr.set_source_rgb(0,255,0)
                    x3 = x2 - 6
                    y3 = y2 - 6
                    self.cr.rectangle(x1+3,y1+3,x3,y3)
                    self.cr.stroke()
                    x = x1 + 3
                    y = y1 + y2 - 3 
                    fraction = int( round( x3 / 12.34 ) )
                    split = float(x3) / float(fraction)  
                    self.cr.set_source_rgba(0,255,0,0.3)
                    for i in range(fraction):
                        x = x + split
                        self.cr.move_to(x,y1+3)
                        self.cr.line_to(x,y)
                    self.cr.stroke()

                    x = x1 + x2 - 3
                    y = y1 + 3 
                    fraction = int( round( y3 / 12.34 ) )
                    split = float(y3) / float(fraction)  
                    self.cr.set_source_rgba(0,255,0,0.3)
                    for i in range(fraction):
                        y = y + split
                        self.cr.move_to(x1+3,y)
                        self.cr.line_to(x,y)
                    self.cr.stroke()
                    y1 = y1 + y2 + 20






class main(gtk.Window):
        __gsignals__ = {
                        "configure-event" : "override"
                        }

        def __init__(self):
                super(main,self).__init__()
                self.set_title("Virtual Machine Monitor")
                self.set_default_size(640,640)
                self.set_resizable(True)
                self.set_geometry_hints(min_width=640,min_height=500)
                self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
                self.connect("delete_event",gtk.main_quit)
                ##self.maximize()
                vbox=gtk.VBox(False,1)
                self.monitor2=Monitor(self,"MEM")
                ##self.monitor3=Monitor(self,"MEM")
                vbox.pack_start(self.monitor2,1,1,0)
                ##vbox.pack_start(self.monitor3,1,1,0)
                self.add(vbox)
                self.show_all()

        def do_configure_event(self, event):

                title = "%s, %s" % (event.x, event.y)
                ##self.set_title(title)
                gtk.Window.do_configure_event(self, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
        gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the freeze_updates and thaw_updates methods of GTK:

```
# GTK Imports
import gtk

gdkwindow=mywindow.window
if gdkwindow:
    gdkwindow.freeze_updates()

# Do cairo drawing operations here


if gdkwindow:
    gdkwindow.thaw_updates()

window.queue_draw()
```

Look for that methods in gdk.window documentation at PyGTK

Answer (score 0):

You might try .`hide`'ing the window before drawing on it, and thus generating the expose when you `.show` it.

The FAQ answer can be found [here.](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq10.021.htp&req=show)